# Yii url manager only ID in url

Tags: url, yii, url-rewriting, controller

i have in YII for example domain: `www.example.com/product-url-1234`

how to set rules in urlManager and how to use `controller/action/id`

Comment: this `/product-url-1234` is dinamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use this url `www.example.eu/product-url-1234`

and suppose `'index'` is the name of the action of the `'user'` controller that will handle the request

Then create a rule like

`'<id:.*?>'=>'user/index'`

Now if you will use `Yii::app()->createUrl('user/index',array('id'=>'product-url-1234'))`

then it will give you the desired result.

And if you Visit this Url, `User/Index` will handle the request.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying forward all request to one controller at root level.

I Assumed that all your request are redirected product/view route

in your config go to URL section,

```
'(.*)'=>'product/view'
    'urlManager' => array(  
      'urlFormat' => 'path',  
      'showScriptName' => false,  
        'rules' => array(  
            '(.*)' => 'product/view',  
            'post/<id:\d+>/<title:.*?>' => 'post/view',  
            'posts/<tag:.*?>' => 'post/index',  
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',  
          ),
```

that means you are capturing all your root requests to product controllers view action

Where you can get  www.example.eu/product-url-1234 using
    `Yii::app()->request->requestUri`  in product/view

but this is not good way to capture all your incoming request to a single controller, the better way would be as follows.

www.example.eu/product/product-url-1234

then you have to change the configuration

```
'product/<product:.*?>'=>'product/view'
    'urlManager' => array(  
      'urlFormat' => 'path',  
      'showScriptName' => false,  
        'rules' => array(  
            'product/<product:.*?>' => 'product/view',  
            'post/<id:\d+>/<title:.*?>' => 'post/view',  
            'posts/<tag:.*?>' => 'post/index',  
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',  
          ),
```

in your view action,  you can get the url through `$_GET['product']`