# Wrong Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl() if called in an error 404 page

Tags: php, yii, error-handling

If I have the following route in config file:

```
'http://<domain:\w+>.com/page_example' => 'controllername',
```

When I call `Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('controllername')` in a view of a custom error 404 page, Yii creates the following link:

```
http://example.com/controllername
```

when it should create the route:

```
http://example.com/page_example
```

It only happens on error pages, main config error handler is defined as:

```
'errorHandler'=>array(
            'errorAction'=>'site/error',
        ),
```

Comment: what is page_example ?? is this an action or an argument that is taken by the controller's action ?

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28063906/yii-url-manager-only-id-in-url/28066109#28066109 might help you

Comment: Hi! page_example is the index action of controllername. The problem is that in all pages except pages of error 404 works ok.